# TeXStudio suddenly compiles a file?

Tags: latex, pdflatex, texstudio

I was working with TexStudio on some document ,and at one moment I see in Messages:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -interaction =nonstopmode -ini "&pdflatex hoXIqxR \dump"
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "ChrgOo".tex
Process exited normally
Process exited normally
```

My question is : I was not compiling anything at that time ,I was surprised to see this happening in messages. I do not recognize any of these files.
What am I dealing with?

Comment: texstudio has quite a lot of build in preview thingies for formulas, images etc. that are surprisingly hard to switch of completely.  This would also fit to the seemingly random filename. These actions are usually triggered if you move your mouse over a formula or similar.

Comment: Can you try with these settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd1Zc.png ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer that may be the case you mentiond. My Auto Update is set to previously previewd text. I don't have Auto Update Delay option at all. Thanks

Comment: (the "auto update delay" option is only visible if the `show advanced options` at the bottom left is activated)